# NullPointException and length of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, constructor

I'm having deep trouble when dealing with an array of objects. Basically what I have defined is the following:

```
public class PlayersList
{
private Player[] players;
private int length;
private int numPlayer = 0;
}
```

Which in this case players come from the data type players:

```
public class Player
{
public String UserName;

public Player(String UserName)
{
this.UserName = UserName;      
}
}
```

Now, when I try to invoke methods that involve traversing through an array of objects or the length of the object array, I get a NPE. I'm starting with a 3 member array, and I have already initialized all three members so that I don't get anything like that. However, if I then try to use something like:

```
  public Player findPlayer(String Player)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
    {
      if(Player.equals(players[i].UserName))
      {
        return players[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And as well in other types of code involving an element of the player array or its length, I get a NPE. What I'm doing wrong? Is there any way to avoid this or could someone tell me what I'm missing? Thank you so much.

**Edit**: Here is the code for initializing players in the array:

```
 public PlayersList()
  {
    Player[] players = new Player[3];
    players[0] = new Player("Hi");
    players[1] = new Player("Bla");
    players[2] = new Player("Foo");
    length = 3;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you initialize the `Player` objects in your array?

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added it now.

Comment: I think there should be another set of braces around the "Player" class.

Comment: To start with, it is important that you don't name local variables with the same name as a class - don't use `String Player` and at the same time refer to the class `Player`. The java code conventions say to always start variable names with lower-case: `String player`. That is a good habit which ensures that you never use the same name for a class and a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a local array here

```
Player[] players = new Player[3];
```

Do this instead

```
players = new Player[3];
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have been the problem all along. Now, out of pure curiosity, what is actually going on with this local array? After I create it it is pretty much lost or does it have any importance?

Comment: When you are done with the constructor, you end up with the array in heap memory but you do not have any reference to it. So it is available for garbage collection. Memory will be freed of this object when garbage collection happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your `players` variable in the constructor is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the field.

```
public class PlayersList
{
    private Player[] players;

    public PlayersList()
    {
        // shadows the field
        Player[] players = new Player[3];

        ...
```

Doing `Player[] players` in the constructor declares *a new variable with the same name*. Remove the type and it becomes an assignment to the field instead of a declaration:

```
    public PlayersList()
    {
        // now refers to the field
        players = new Player[3];
```